# Extract all sheets with the same value in a specific cell to a new workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a file with 300+ tabs for each employee's sales commission.  Some of the employees are on a team of 2-6 employees.  Team name is on each tab, even if it is a team of one, is in Cell AA3.  I would like to have VBA Code to extract all of the sheets where AA3 (Team Name) is the same to a new file named "Team " & $AA$3.

I have a macro to extract each sheet to a new file, but I cannot figure out how to write the loop correctly to do what I am asking.

The code I have that extracts each sheet to a new file is as follows:

```
    Sub Copy_Every_Sheet_To_New_Workbook_2()
    'Working in 97-2010
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DateString As String
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim TEAM As String
    Dim Team2 As String


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'Copy every sheet from the workbook with this macro
    Set Sourcewb = ThisWorkbook

    'Create new folder to save the new files in
    DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
    FolderName = Sourcewb.Path & "\" & Sourcewb.Name & " " & DateString
    MkDir FolderName

    'Copy every visible sheet to a new workbook
    For Each sh In Sourcewb.Worksheets

        'If the sheet is visible then copy it to a new workbook
        If sh.Visible = -1 Then
            sh.Copy

            'Set Destwb to the new workbook
            Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

            'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
            With Destwb
                If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                    'You use Excel 97-2003
                    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
                Else
                    'You use Excel 2007-2010
                    If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
                        MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
                        GoTo GoToNextSheet
                    Else
                        Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
                        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                        Case 52:
                            If .HasVBProject Then
                                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                            Else
                                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                            End If
                        Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
                        Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
                        End Select
                    End If
                End If
            End With

            'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
            If Destwb.Sheets(1).ProtectContents = False Then
                With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
                    .Cells.Copy
                    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .Cells(1).Select
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If


            'Save the new workbook and close it
            With Destwb
                .SaveAs FolderName & "\" & Destwb.Sheets(1).Range("AK2").Value & FileExtStr, _
                        FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
                .Close False
            End With

        End If
GoToNextSheet:
    Next sh

    MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `I hope this is enough information` ... enough information will be the code you've written so far. We can help you get your code working much better, if you post what you have so far, and tell us where it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation!  I have added what I have written so far.  Thank you.

Comment: I have to run, but in short, you need to create a list of team's name, loop through that list, and write something like `If sh.Range("AA3") = TeamName (this is a variable) Then copy to new workbook`. If you put this after `If sh.Visible = -1 Then` ..  that seems like a good place for it.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Scott's suggestion, here's a function that will return all of the unique values in a workbook, for a given cell address.  It takes advantage of the Collection object and the fact that you can only add unique values to it.  For example, the 2nd time you try to add "Team A" it will skip it (inside the On Error statements):

```
Function GetUniqueCellValues(wb As Excel.Workbook, cellAddress As String) As Collection
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim coll As Collection

Set coll = New Collection
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    coll.Add ws.Range(cellAddress).Value, ws.Range(cellAddress).Text
    On Error GoTo 0
Next ws
Set GetUniqueCellValues = coll
End Function
```

I like to try to code functions so that they rely on what's currently in the workbook, or whatever, rather than hardcoding a list.

You'd call it like this if you wanted every unique value in cell `AA3` of all sheets in the workbook containing the code, i.e., `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Sub test()

Dim collTeamNames As Collection
Dim i As Long

Set collTeamNames = GetUniqueCellValues(ThisWorkbook, "AA3")
For i = 1 To collTeamNames.Count
Debug.Print collTeamNames(i)
    'do your processing here
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you!  This was something I had wanted to do for a while and it will save me several hours.  You responses were appreciated!

Comment: This seems to only work with strings, numbers don't add themselves to the collection??

Comment: @Mallow, good catch! The `On Error Resume Next` was masking the Type Mismatch error caused by trying to add a number as the key. I'll edit the offending line to: `coll.Add ws.Range(cellAddress).Value, ws.Range(cellAddress).Text`